# cv2.imshow and cv2.imwrite

Tags: python, opencv

Can someone explain why the OpenCV `imshow` and `imwrite` function seem to result in a completely different image?

The first picture corresponds to `imshow` and the second picture corresponds to `imwrite`.
`Result` is an array of floating point values between 0 and 255.

```
**result = result.astype(np.uint8)**
cv2.imshow('img', result)
cv2.imwrite('img.png', result)
```

[image: Target]
[image: Result]

Comment: 1 took the 1st pic and tried, and i get the 1st pic for both (but i'm on opencv3.0 here)

Comment: I use Python version 3.3

Comment: which opencv version are you using ? is it using opencv's png libs or something from your system ? try: cv2.getBuildInformation()

Comment: no idea atm, but it's definitely not the normal outcome

Comment: even cast the result array (via result.astype(np.uint8)); doesn't work

Comment: I think `imshow` assumes a range of [0,1] for floating point datatypes, whereas it assumes a range of [0,255] for uchar images. However, `imwrite` assumes a range of [0,255] for both floating point and uchar images.

Comment: imwrite does not handle float images at all.

Comment: but the cast to integer results in the same image

Comment: `result.astype(np.uint8)` does not change the result object. You need to assign the return value of that operation to something.

Comment: Thx now they're both the same except that both images look like the one underneath. But I thought 0.5 * (1+cos(x^2+y^2)) would look somewhat less dense on [0,48)x[0,48)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I used the following (c++) code with OpenCV 2.4.8:

```
cv::Mat_<float> img(300,300);
cv::theRNG().fill(img,cv::RNG::UNIFORM,0,255);
cv::imshow("Img",img);
cv::waitKey();
cv::imwrite("test.png",img);
```

and it results in the following images:

[image]

with `imshow`.

[image]

with `imwrite`.

**This is due to the different range expectation of the two functions**, `imwrite` always expects [0,255], whereas `imshow` expects [0,1] for floating point and [0,255] for unsigned chars.

In order to display the correct output with `imshow`, you need to reduce the range of your floating point image from [0,255] to [0,1]. You can do this using `convertTo` and an appropriate scaling factor, or simply by dividing your image by 255.

Comment: But with **result = result.astype(np.uint8)** both images look now the same with values between [0,255] which is also the case for some other projects.

Comment: oh, so the (sparse) 1st image is actually the result of saturating anything > 1 to 1 in the float image ?

Comment: @berak yes the first image is saturated.

Comment: commenting result = result.astype(np.uint8) seems to result in two different images and uncommenting seems to result in two similar images

Comment: @Matthias If you convert your floating point image to unsigned char without modifying the values, then you have a unsigned char image with [0,255] values, hence both functions have the same behavior. If you don't convert the type, you have a floating point image with values [0,255], hence the two functions have different behavior.

Comment: Don't you mean unsigned int? But anyway the dense image is the right one?

Comment: @Matthias Yes the dense image is the right one. And `uint8` is an unsigned int on 8 bits, which is an `unsigned char`. Standard `unsigned int` is usually on 32 bits ;)

Comment: ah yes you're right; I didn't gave much attention to the strange python naming

Answer (score 2):

since you are using python this might help :

```
def showimg(img):
    cv2.namedWindow("test", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    img = np.array(img,dtype=float)/float(255)
    cv2.imshow('test',img)
    cv2.resizeWindow('test',600,600)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```